# configuration of billing field using paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm using express checkout to do a payment page. When paying with credit card paypal asks for all the billing that, that in this scenario is not required.
  Is possibile to remove the unnecessary fields and shows just the ones required to do the payment?

thanks,
  Luca

Comment: What do you believe PayPal is asking for that is not required? If you mean credit card billing address, this is widely used (including by PayPal) for fraud detection. If you step up to PayPal's "vetted" merchant products they will let you do your own stripped-down card form if you want to take on the fraud responsibility (and the higher interchange costs for each transaction). But with Express Checkout PayPal is the merchant of record on the card network and they will be taking industry-standard anti-fraud protections based on billing address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot adjust the form that PayPal provides for credit cards (guest checkout) in Express Checkout.  You could upgrade to [Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) if you want to, and depending on you're vetted they may give you full access to fraud filters to that you can limit the number of fields required.  That's no guarantee, though.